# Number of passwords with requirements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

For a password of 8 length with at least 2 uppercase, 2 numbers, and the rest either plus lowercase, where we can have repeats, how many passwords can I generate if I have "9" "0" "X" "x" "y' in my password already?

I would think something along the lines of:
Let's say we have the password as NNUUAAAA where N is a number, U is uppercase and A is all. I can view it as 90XUxyAA. Then I would have $$26 \cdot 62^2$$ possibilities. But I also have to see the number of permutations for my "word" NNUUAAAA, which I see as 8!/(2!2!4!). The answer is 420 anagrams possible. Then my answer would be $$420 \cdot 26 \cdot 62^2. $$

Is this correct?

Comment: That's not quite correct because it does not account for non-duplicate entries. You shold by the way avoid deleting and re-asking the same question; try instead to update the original question.

Comment: My previous question was not deleted and it is not the same question, same conditions but putting certain values as requirements changes a lot IMO, which is why I thought a new post would be better. Can you explain how it doesn't account for duplicates?

Comment: If you have a password like $90XYxyab$ where all entries are different, then the number of permutations for this password will be $8!$.

Comment: The 8!/(2!2!4!) isn't to account for repeats of characters in the password, but the repeat in the type of character. If all types are different then it would be 8!, but I divided by 2!2!4! because there are repeated types. Am I thinking about this wrong?

Comment: Also yes. You must be sure to account for all possibilities in a manner that does not overcount or undercount, so each time you make a calculation you must be sure that no case escapes your assumption. Another approach would be to embrace overcounting and go inclusion-exclusion. I don't think this problem has a nifty solution and you may need to go nitty-gritty and deal with cases (such as 'suppose the AAAA are of these types' and 'suppose the letters have this many repetitions').